# Why I am getting different $R^2$ from R LM and manual calculation?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I did a toy experiment with linear regression, but getting different results for $R^2$, could any one help me?

```
library(ggplot2)
fit=lm(price~carat+depth+table+x+y+z-1,data=diamonds)
summary(fit)
sse=crossprod(diamonds$price-fit$fitted.values)
sst=crossprod(diamonds$price-mean(diamonds$price))
1-sse/sst
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem.

I am not adding the intercept in the model and without intercept SST is calculated differently, where it should be

`crossprod(diamonds$price)`

but not

`crossprod(diamonds$price-mean(diamonds$price))`

I think most books are confusing that just give us the formula to SST as

$$
\|y-\bar y\|^2
$$

but not mention such formula only holds for model with intercept term.

Comment: You're correct but I believe this effectively duplicates a number of questions already on site.